# ValueError: None values not supported. Code working properly on CPU/GPU but not on TPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tpu

I am trying to train a `seq2seq` model for language translation, and I am copy-pasting code from this [Kaggle Notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/aiswaryaramachandran/english-to-hindi-neural-machine-translation/notebook) on Google Colab. The code is working fine with CPU and GPU, but it is giving me errors while training on a TPU. This same question has been already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66189494/training-seq2seq-model-on-google-colab-tpu-with-big-dataset-keras).

Here is my code:

```
    strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(resolver)
    
    with strategy.scope():
      model = create_model()
      model.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy')
    
    model.fit_generator(generator = generate_batch(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size),
                        steps_per_epoch = train_samples // batch_size,
                        epochs = epochs,
                        validation_data = generate_batch(X_test, y_test, batch_size = batch_size),
                        validation_steps = val_samples // batch_size)
```

Traceback:

```
Epoch 1/2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-940fe0ee3c8b> in <module>()
      3                     epochs = epochs,
      4                     validation_data = generate_batch(X_test, y_test, batch_size = batch_size),
----> 5                     validation_steps = val_samples // batch_size)

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    992           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    993             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 994               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    995             else:
    996               raise

ValueError: in user code:
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:853 train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:842 step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
...
ValueError: None values not supported.
```

I couldn't figure out the error, and I think the error is because of this `generate_batch` function:

```
X, y = lines['english_sentence'], lines['hindi_sentence']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 34)

def generate_batch(X = X_train, y = y_train, batch_size = 128):
    while True:
        for j in range(0, len(X), batch_size):
 
            encoder_input_data = np.zeros((batch_size, max_length_src), dtype='float32')
            decoder_input_data = np.zeros((batch_size, max_length_tar), dtype='float32')
            decoder_target_data = np.zeros((batch_size, max_length_tar, num_decoder_tokens), dtype='float32')
            
            for i, (input_text, target_text) in enumerate(zip(X[j:j + batch_size], y[j:j + batch_size])):
                for t, word in enumerate(input_text.split()):
                    encoder_input_data[i, t] = input_token_index[word]
                for t, word in enumerate(target_text.split()):
                    if t<len(target_text.split())-1:
                        decoder_input_data[i, t] = target_token_index[word]
                    if t>0:

                        decoder_target_data[i, t - 1, target_token_index[word]] = 1.
            yield([encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data], decoder_target_data)
```

My Colab notebook - [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PMHr6dNKR8HFVLM9ngH8jBhkxEZhp-E1?usp=sharing)
Kaggle dataset - [here](https://www.kaggle.com/aiswaryaramachandran/hindienglish-corpora)
TensorFlow version - `2.6`

**Edit** - Please don't tell me to down-grade TensorFlow/Keras version to `1.x`. I can down-grade it to `TensorFlow 2.0, 2.1, 2.3` but not `1.x`. I don't understand `TensorFlow 1.x`. Also, there is no point in using a 3-year-old version.

Comment: Does you dataset have None/Null values?
What version of Tensorflow are you using?, it should work fine with TF 2.5+.

Comment: @Gagik, TF 2.6 : Yes, it has some NaN values, I have dropped them, but it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: I looked at your code and you dont add OOV token to your vocabulary(+1) what will happen if an unseen word enter to the model?

Comment: Can you try model with dummy data like this please?                                                       xx = [np.random.rand(20,30), np.random.rand(20,30)]
yy = np.random.rand(20,30)

model.fit(x=xx, y=yy, epochs = 2)  I cant figure out your models input outputshapes. If you try with dummy data on TPU maybe we can understand where is the bug

Comment: I can't fit that dummy data: ValueError: Shapes (None, None) and (None, 30, 81978) are incompatible

Comment: Oh ok , i thought you designed this model. Cpu and gpu training happens on one processor, but for tpu training: model mirrors itself for every tpu core. So you need to be little bit more cautious for re-distributing the losses and other metrics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the referenced answer in the link you provided, `tensorflow.data` API works better with TPUs. In order to adapt it in your case, try to use `return` instead of `yield` in `generate_batch` function:

```
def generate_batch(X = X_train, y = y_train, batch_size = 128):
    ...
    return encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data, decoder_target_dat

encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data, decoder_target_data = generate_batch(X_train, y_train, batch_size=128)
```

And then use `tensorflow.data` to structure your data:

```
from tensorflow.data import Dataset

encoder_input_data = Dataset.from_tensor_slices(encoder_input_data)
decoder_input_data = Dataset.from_tensor_slices(decoder_input_data)
decoder_target_data = Dataset.from_tensor_slices(decoder_target_data)
ds = Dataset.zip((encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data, decoder_target_data)).map(map_fn).batch(1024)
```

where `map_fn` is defined by:

```
def map_fn(encoder_input ,decoder_input, decoder_target):
    return (encoder_input ,decoder_input), decoder_target
```

And finally use `Model.fit` instead of `Model.fit_generator`:

```
model.fit(x=ds, epochs=epochs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to down-grade to Keras 1.0.2
If works then great, otherwise I will tell other solution.

Comment: No, I want to use TensorFlow and Keras 2.x. I don't understand 1.x version. Can you tell me any solution using 2.x?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update Keras and your problem will be fixed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am using TensorFlow 2.6 (Keras included), and 2.6 is the latest version., **I can't update it anymore.**